# Centering a Twitter Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a form with Twitter Bootstrap, and am having a really difficult time centering the button. It's contained inside a div with a span of 7. Below is the HTML, and the button is at the very bottom. Any recommendations on how to center this thing?

```
<div class="form span7">
  <div id="get-started">
    <div id="form-intro">
      <strong><h1>1. Get Started: Some basics</h1></strong>
    </div>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputSaving">What are you saving for?</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input class="span4" type="text" id="inputSaving" placeholder="e.g. Swimming Lessons, Birthday Party, College Fund, etc.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="description">Add a short description</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <textarea class="span4" id="description" rows="4" placeholder="Describe in your own words the saving goal for this piggybank"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="categoryselect">Choose a Category</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <select class="span4" id="categoryselect">
            <!-- Add some CSS and JS to make a placeholder value-->
            <option value="Kittens">Kittens</option>
            <option value="Keyboard Cat">Keyboard Cat</option>
            <option value="Twitter Bird">Twitter Bird</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="imageselect">Choose an image</label>
        <div class="controls span4">
          <img src="piggyimage.png" id="imageselect" alt="image-select" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="goal">Your Saving Goal</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" class="span4" id="goal" placeholder="$1337">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 66):

Bootstrap has it's own centering class named **text-center**.

`<div class="span7 text-center"></div>`

Comment: Best answer uses the API

Comment: Just too bad that it doesn't work with `<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg span7">` !

Answer (score 30):

If you don't mind a bit more markup, this would work:

```
<div class="centered">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

With the corresponding CSS rule:

```
.centered
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

I have to look at the CSS rules for the `btn` class, but I don't think it specifies a width, so `auto` left & right margins wouldn't work. If you added one of the `span` or `input-` rules to the button, auto margins **would** work, though.

**Edit:**

Confirmed my initial thought; the `btn` classes do **not** have a width defined, so you can't use auto side margins. Also, as [@AndrewM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1170128/andrewm) notes, you could simply use the `text-center` class instead of creating a new ruleset.

Comment: Even better you could use bootstraps `text-center` class and not have to write any css yourself. for example `<div class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button></div>`

Answer (score 18):

Wrap in a div styled with "text-center" class.

Comment: This worked for me, my button will remain centered even with the viewport causes Bootstrap to put the button on the nextline. '     <div class="col-sm-1 text-center">
        <input type="submit" value="Search Again" class="btn btn-primary"/>
     </div>'

Answer (score 11):

Question is a bit old, but easy way is to apply .center-block to button.

Comment: Problem is that this makes the button width fill its container as well

Comment: This worked just fine for me, but only when using a form <button>.  Applying the btn classes to a <div> filled the parent element.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to center the button, and not the text, what I've done in the past is add a class, then use that class to center the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary newclass" type="button">Submit</button>
```

and the CSS would be:

```
.btn.newclass {width:25%; display:block; margin: 0 auto;}
```

The "width" value is up to you, and you can play with that to get the right look.

Steve

Comment: Why force the element to appear block-level. Better use Bootstraps build in solutions

Answer (score 3):

```
.span7.btn { display: block;   margin-left: auto;   margin-right: auto; }
```

I am not completely familiar with bootstrap, but something like the above should do the trick. It may not be necessary to include all of the classes. This should center the button within its parent, the span7.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one button, then you can do the following.

```
<div class="center-block" style="max-width:400px">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Accept</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"> Reject</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap have a specific class for this:
center-block

```
<button type="button" class="your_class center-block"> Book </button>
```